# How to set outline to its parent when textbox get focussed using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, textbox

i tried myself and searched alot, but i did not get clear answer. It may be due to i am newbie to angularjs. i have textbox which is wrapped inside div like:

```
<div class="email-icon"><input type="text" class="input-field clearfix email"  ng-focus="focusIn()" ng-blur="focusOut()"></div>
```

Now i want whenever textbox get focus then outline the div. for this i have create these two function in my app.js, but unfotunatly i am not getting even which element called this fucntion.

```
$scope.focusIn = function(event){
    console.log('Focussed :)'+event);
  }
   $scope.focusOut = function(){
    console.log('Out of focus :(');
  }
```

Please, Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the event when you call your functions

```
<input type="text" class="input-field clearfix email" ng-focus="focusIn($event)" ng-blur="focusOut($event)"/>
```

Than in your controller you can get the parent of the element that received focus

```
$scope.focusIn = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).parent().addClass('focus');
};

$scope.focusOut = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).parent().removeClass('focus');
};
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/9mce1em1/1/

Comment: Thanks Buddy. what exactly i want. Could you please refer to me good resource to learn angularjs like above example.

Comment: @Mandy: I've learned a lot from these video's: 
https://egghead.io/playlists/new-to-angular-start-here

angular documentation isn't bad, and of course stack overflow can answer most of your questions.

Comment: Thank buddy for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS is a easy way to do what do you want, instead of using some javascript code, angular have directives that allow you do this like ng-class. For example when you get focus to textbox, you could bind that action to a boolean variable and using a directive like I mentioned before in the div, you can obtain good results in easy way. First try to know about what are provided in AngularJS and when you can't find what you looking for, then try to do you own solution, AngularJS have many good directives implemented.
In CSS file you could have some like this:

```
.div-outlined{ border: solid 2px red; }
```

In html some like this:

```
<div id="containerdiv" ng-class="{'div-outlined': textboxfocus === true}">
  <input type="text" ng-focus="textboxfocus = true"/>
</div>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Buddy your code also do the same thing, but i can only accept one. Thanks for your reply.